# How to overcome default constraint in vertica

Tags: talend, netezza, vertica

I am loading data from Netezza to vertica through talend. With out any interruption i want to load data from source to destination. But i am getting below error

Caused by: com.vertica.support.exceptions.FeatureNotSupportedException: [Vertica]VJDBC ERROR: Column **COLUMNNAME** has the NOT NULL constraint set and has no default value defined.

The column name in both NETEZZA & VERTICA tables defined as NOT NULL.

Please anyone can help on this. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

You would have to look at your logfiles.

Independently of the ETL tool, there will be a `SELECT *` against the source (in your case, Netezza) , or a SELECT with all columns of the table, and an `INSERT /*+DIRECT */ INTO <table> (col1,col2,..., coln) VALUES (?,?,...,?)` against your target (in your case, Vertica). You will have to check whether all columns of the table are mentioned in both statements.

I have the suspicion that the column triggering the error is not mentioned.

Check the log files.

Good luck - 
Marco

Comment: Marco, but same column names in both Netezza and vertica

Comment: Same column names in Netezza and Vertica don't help if Talend does not select all columns from Netezza and/or does not use all columns for the INSERT in Vertica. You can only find that out if you check Talend's log files, really.